# Specifying R as language in nbformat

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

Using help from [here](https://gist.github.com/fperez/9716279), I'm writing a python code to generate a Jupyter notebook. My code goes as:

```
...
code1 = """\
a=[1,2,3]
for x in a:
    print(x)"""
cell1=nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code1)
code2="""\
myString <- 'Hello, World!'
print(myString)"""                  #note that it is in R
cell2=nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code2)
...
```

I'm using `!jupyter nbconvert --execute --inplace test.ipynb` to execute my code, so that I can see the outputs without having to run the final notebook.

Now the thing is that I want `cell1` to be run using python, which is the default (I guess) and `cell2` using R. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks...

Comment: The code is executed using the defined kernel. The kernel is defined in the notebooks 'metadata' - not in the cells metadata. Therefore I'm not sure you can have different kernels for the same notebook.

In any case, here the documentation of where/how to define the kernel(spec): https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html#notebook-metadata

Comment: @fanfabbb But in jupyter notebook, we can change the kernel for a specific cell right?

Comment: I don't think so. It's single kernel per notebook. Here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2815 is a discussion on it - there appears to be custom kernels that combine multiple languages but I guess that's a bit of a hack and to be used with caution.